# Image Processing Pipeline

Tags: c++, template, polymorphism

I'm currently toying around with some Computer Vision algorithms and always wanted to learn more about templates, so I came up with the idea to build a templated Image Processing Pipeline.

I want the pipeline to be built of several task blocks which I want to plug into each other *sequentially*. For a specific block, its input and output types are fixed. I ultimately want to be able to inherently control for a block to only accept the next block if the output type of the current is identical to the input type of the next.

> ```
>          Block_N                 Block_N+1
>      _______________         _________________ 
> int |               |  str  |                 | float
> --->| str = f1(int) |------>| float = f2(str) |------->
>     |_______________|       |_________________|
> ```

Consequently, `Block_N+2` would have to accept `float` as input and may have an arbitrary output type.

This is what I was able to come up with:

**Abstract base classes:**

```cpp
template<class I>
class AbstractInput {

public:
    virtual ~AbstractInput() { }

    virtual void call( I _input ) = 0;
};


template<class I, class O>
class AbstractPipelineTask : public AbstractInput<I> {

public:
    typedef AbstractInput<O>* Ptr;

    AbstractPipelineTask( AbstractInput<O>* _nextTask = NULL) 
        : m_nextTask ( _nextTask ) { }

    virtual void call( I _input ) {

        m_input = _input;
        m_output = executeTask( m_input );

        if ( m_nextTask )
            m_nextTask->call( m_output );
    }

    virtual O executeTask( I& _input ) = 0;

protected:  
    AbstractInput<O>* m_nextTask;

    I m_input;
    O m_output;
};
```

**Example implementation:**

```cpp
class Str2IntPipelineTask : public AbstractPipelineTask< std::string, int > {

public:
    Str2IntPipelineTask( AbstractInput<int>* _nextTask = NULL ) 
        : AbstractPipelineTask( _nextTask ) { }
    virtual ~Str2IntPipelineTask() { }

    virtual int executeTask( std::string& _input ) {

        return atoi( _input.c_str() );
    }
};

class Int2IntPipelineTask : public AbstractPipelineTask< int, int> {

public:
    Int2IntPipelineTask( AbstractInput<int>* _nextTask = NULL ) 
        : AbstractPipelineTask( _nextTask ) { }
    virtual ~Int2IntPipelineTask() { }

    virtual int executeTask( int& _input ) {

        return ( _input * _input );
    }
};

class Int2FloatPipelineTask : public AbstractPipelineTask< int, float > {

public:
    Int2FloatPipelineTask( AbstractInput<float>* _nextTask = NULL ) 
        : AbstractPipelineTask( _nextTask ) { }
    virtual ~Int2FloatPipelineTask() { }

    virtual float executeTask( int& _input ) {

        return ( static_cast<float>( _input ) / 42.f );
    }
};
```

**Examples:**

```cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Int2FloatPipelineTask* pipeTask2    = new Int2FloatPipelineTask( );
    Int2IntPipelineTask* pipeTask1      = new Int2IntPipelineTask( pipeTask2 );
    Str2IntPipelineTask* pipeTask0      = new Str2IntPipelineTask( pipeTask1 );

    pipeTask0->call( "42" );

    return 0;
}
```

What I would really like to know besides some general advice is:

- How can I get rid of the raw pointers `AbstractInput<O>* m_nextTask`? I tried changing the `typedef` of `Ptr` to `std::shared_ptr<AbstractInput<O>>` but that broke the derived classes constructors.
- Is it possible to get rid of `AbstractInput`?

Comment: Do you accept C++11 or do you absolutely need to stick to C++03 for some reason?

Comment: Actually, I don't really care, because I'd just love to see some elegant solution. But most likely, I won't have C++11 and most parts of the stl available in my final environment

Comment: [Here's](http://ideone.com/qSj3l2) one way to do this. If you get rid of all the C++11 stuff in this example, you'll have to create each pipeline task before calling `operator>>` in `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since none of these `class`es have `private` members, they can be `struct`s instead.  As such, you'll no longer need to explicitly give them `public` inheritance.
- Consider making the magic number `42.f` a constant so that its intent is known.
- This is specific to Visual Studio, thus is non-portable:

  > ```
  > int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  > ```

  It should be changed to this to fit the standard:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  ```
- In your various `executeTask()` functions, I believe you're meaning to pass by `const&`, not just by reference.  You're not modifying the argument, so `const` is best with them.